# Is it possible to get the base URL for an express router

Tags: node.js, express

I have an authentication middleware that needs to make a call to an outside service and provide a callback URL. For example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// This will work just fine
app.use('/', getAuthRouter());

// The redirects here will end up going to /oauth/callback 
//    instead of /admin/oauth/callback
app.use('/admin', getAuthRouter());

function getAuthRouter() {
  var authRouter = express.Router();

  // Setup auth routes
  var callbackUrl = '/oauth/callback';
  var loginUrl    = '/login';

  authRouter.get(callbackUrl, .... });
  authRouter.get(loginUrl, function(req, res, next){
    // Make call to OAuth server
    res.redirect("http://authserver/?callback=" + callbackUrl);
  });

  return authRouter;
}
```

The problem is that `authRouter` does not know that it's actually mounted under `/admin` so it has no way to prepend that to the `callback` param.

Is there any way that I can get that inside the `getAuthRouter` function?

Comment: Interestingly, there is an `app.mountpath` which would accomplish this, but it's only if you mount a sub-app and not a router. This happens right [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L214-L221)

Answer (score 10):

Use [request.baseUrl](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.baseUrl), which was designed for this use case.

Comment: `baseUrl` is just the URL path on which a router instance was mounted. So if you had `app.use('/auth', routes)`. The `baseUrl` would be `/auth` not the actual baseUrl OP is looking for

Answer (score 3):

**Use `req.url`:**

You can use `req.url`.
If you are on `http://example.com/test/here` it will return `/test/here`.

**Pass it as argument:**

But in your case you could also pass the base url as a parameter of your middleware :

```
function getAuthRouter(baseUrl) {
  var authRouter = express.Router();
  baseUrl = baseUrl || ""; // Default

  // Setup auth routes
  var callbackUrl = baseUrl + '/oauth/callback';
  var loginUrl    = '/login';
  // ...
}
```

And you'll then call it like so :

`app.use('/admin', getAuthRouter("/admin"));`

Or

`app.use ('/', getAuthRouter()); // Calls default`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. While this is a totally valid approach, I wanted to avoid having to manually pass anything into the middleware and was more looking for a self-discovery approach.

Comment: Then you should probably use the `req.url` way !